# Поиск и замена регулярным выражением в БД MySQL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mysql

Доброго времени суток господа, прошу простить за откровенность, но мне нужно именно решение моей задачи так как я не уверен что сам сделаю все верно.

В определенной таблице БД около 1000 записей в которых присутствует вот такой код

```
<a href=\"some_path_to_image/1.jpg\" onclick=\"window.open(\'some_path_to_image/1.jpg\',\'\',\'width=490,height=620,left=\'+(screen.availWidth/2-245)+\',top=\'+(screen.availHeight/2-310)+\'\');return false;\">
<img src=\"some_path_to_image/thumb_1.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"266\" height=\"345\" style=\"border: 1px solid #4d2612;\" /></a>
```

Сие чудо открывает большое изображение в новом окне по клику на превью.

Подскажите запрос к БД чтобы эта строка стала такого вида

```
<a href=\"some_path_to_image/1.jpg\" rel="lightbox[plants]">
<img src=\"some_path_to_image/thumb_1.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"266\" height=\"345\" style=\"border: 1px solid #4d2612;\" /></a>
```

при условии что данные которые находятся внутри `window.open()` разные.

З.Ы. Если сие сложно сделать на уровне БД то сразу так и скажите, тогда буду делать регуляркой средствами php, но минус в том что размер данных в таблице в которой это все живет не мал.

За ранее бланодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то вот таким образом можно:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col` = CONCAT (
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`col`, "onclick", 1),
    "rel=\"lightbox[plants]\"",
    SUBSTRING(`col`, LOCATE(">", `col`, LOCATE("onclick", `col`)))
)
```

Но я бы, наверно, всё равно предпочел бы делать это на уровне PHP. И вообще, я не люблю регулярки ))

Comment: Решение на php уже готово, счя сделаю свежий бэкап базы и буду пробывать тем и теп способом! Сайт просто живой, нужно аккуратно) Спасибо!

Comment: Да да... Бэкапы - это наше всё ;)